# Titanium PayPal module submission rejected by Apple because of Non-public API usage

Tags: paypal, titanium, titanium-mobile, appstore-approval, titanium-modules

It works fine in enterprise account, I can use it to pay real money, but when I upload it to appstore, error exists.
"Your app contains non-public API usage......"

The module I used is downloaded from https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_modules/tree/master/paypal

For detail,please see the attachment photo.
Hope someone can help.

[image: the errors]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I got the solution.

As the Ti module is using the old version of libPayPalMPL.a, which reference uniqueIdentifier.

I tried to download the very new version(UDID problem fixed) libPayPalMPL.a from [paypal github](https://github.com/paypal/sdk-packages/tree/gh-pages/MPL), and built the Ti module with this, then used that Ti module for my project.

Thanks Paypal Support Team modified quickly for libPayPalMPL.a and thanks for all replies in this post.